# Is there a way to control the start point and range of the average function with a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have some numerical data in a column, I want a 'user' to be able to select the starting cell and the last cell or range of the average.

I have tried using a combination of the average function and the choose function. I have also tried using AVERAGEIF.

```
=AVERAGEIF(C2:C121, 5, C2:C6)
```

I would like to assign the range within the larger range to a user selected variable. (By the user changing one number preferably)

Comment: You could use an indirect sell reference to define one of the ends of the range.

Comment: @Neo Just so I get it right, if we had eg. range `example` =  [`1`, `2`, `3`] and did the following `=SPECIALAVG(example, 2)` the result would be `1+2/2` or am I getting this wrong? Probably would be preferable if you posted a clear example of expected input and output *(in your original question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55596434/edit))*

Comment: @Rawrplus I have data example (1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7) i would like the user to select the start point of the average e.g C2 and the number of cells after that selected cell to create the range of an average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data in column **A**.  In **B1** enter the start and stop rows for the average like:

```
1,6
```

In another cell, enter:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A"&LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1)&" :A"&MID(B1,FIND(",",B1)+1,9999)))
```

For example:

[image]

*(It is worth exploring the possibility of using `INDEX()` rather than `INDIRECT()`)*

Answer (score 2):

For a non Voltile option use INDEX:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,G1):INDEX(A:A,G2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this works also

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C" & G1):INDIRECT("C" & G2))
```

Where G1 is the start of the range and G2 is the end